# How to capture file conversion status through J Meter into a Web application which has third party app integrated such as neevia converter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, capture, status

How to capture file conversion status through JMeter into a Web application which has third party app integrated such as neevia converter?

Answer (score 1):

If the 3rd-party converter doesn't report the progress/status to the web application you won't be able to access it using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

---

If you have access to the machine where the 3rd-party converter is running via [Powershell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6) (Windows) or [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/) (Unix and derivatives like Linux, MacOS) you can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) or [SSH Command](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) Sampler in order to log into the remote machine and check conversion status/logs.

Check out [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) article for more information on the concept, example configurations, etc.